# What does ~ mean in the YML configuration file in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, yaml

What does ~ mean in the YML configuration file in Symfony 2?

For example:

```
NotBlank: ~
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In Yaml, `~` means null. (*[source](http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/page/basic_types_in_yaml.htm)*)

The actual meaning in Symfony 2 depends on what you are configuring. Most likely it will mean "use defaults" or it will be used where it is needed to put a configuration key but there is nothing to actually configure for that key (as in the NotBlank example).