# What is the purpose of tilde character ~ in YAML?

Tags: yaml

I have looked into YAML official documentation and I have also gone through some tutorials.

I am working with Symfony and I like adding configurations with YAML. But I can't find any explanation for this tilde character `~` in YAML.

For example, see the code below:

```
firewalls:
    # ...
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
```

Sometimes, I removed this ~ character and I did not see any effect on logic. So what is the purpose of this tide character in YAML?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667766/what-does-mean-in-the-yml-configuration-file-in-symfony-2

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The tilde is one of the ways the null value can be written. Most parsers also accept an empty value for null, and of course `null`, `Null` and `NULL`.

These are defined in the first two lines of the regular expressions for the [core schema tags](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2805071) in the YAML standard.