# What's the meaning of tilde in Github Action workflow listened events

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I found the following GitHub Actions workflow in a repository

```yaml
name: Test workflow
on:
  push: ~
  pull_request:
    branches: [ dev, main ]
jobs:
  ...
```

I know `~` means `null` in [YAML world](https://yaml.org/type/null.html), but it can represent "default value" depending on where it is used.

In GitHub Action context, what does the tilde (`~`) on the [push event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push) line means ? It looks like it does nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of tilde character ~ in YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990175/what-is-the-purpose-of-tilde-character-in-yaml)

Comment: Your Github link carries an identifier for the French language.

Answer (score 1):

The normal [syntax for `on:`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on) would be:

```yaml
  on: push
```

Here, you need a sequence below `on:`, because push is not the only criteria.
However, `push:` itself does not need (in this instance) any more argument/sequence.
Hence, the `~` (empty sequence) used as a value.

It should be the same as

```yaml
  on:
    push
```